# Recover table rates without admin export (1.8)

Tags: magento-1.8

I have an old (broken) Magento shop in 1.8.

I need to see the table rates that I have imported years ago. 
But the export to csv is not working. 
(Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'CONFIG_ESCAPING_FLAG')

There must be an other way to see the table rates, anyone can help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any other way to see imported rate. but you can check in database table named `**shipping_tablerate**. all the table rate are saved in this table.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a perfect solution that worked.

Comment: You are welcome :)